# Specified file not found when launching my ASP.NET MVC website through IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I've deployed my ASP.NET MVC website on IIS 8 by creating a file system thanks to Visual Studio and putting the files into a folder located on C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyFolder . When I try to launch my WebSite through IIS (so explore *:3500 which corresponds to localhost:3500), I've got that error :

```
Description : An unhandled exception has occurred during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Exception details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: the system cannot find the file specified

Source error : 


Ligne 1 :  @Html.DevExpress().Scheduler(
Ligne 2 :  settings => {
Ligne 3 :      

Source file : c:\inetpub\wwwroot\AstellasHDJ\Views\Home\SchedulerPartial.cshtml    Ligne : 1 

Stack trace: 


[Win32Exception (0x80004005): Le fichier spécifié est introuvable]

[SqlException (0x80131904)]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +6564850
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +815
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover) +6590016
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover) +219
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) +6592544
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +6592983
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData) +878
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +1162
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +72
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +6596173
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +103
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +2102
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +116
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +1079
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +6600667
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +233
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +278
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +239
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlConnectionManager.UseConnection(IConnectionUser user) +55
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.get_IsSqlCe() +38
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.InitializeProviderMode() +30
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query) +63
   System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator() +63
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +446
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +80
   System.Data.Linq.Provider.BindingList.Create(DataContext context, IEnumerable`1 sequence) +139
   System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.ComponentModel.IListSource.GetList() +29
   DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.Internal.DataSourceHelper.GetResolvedDataSource(Object dataSource, String dataMember) +81
   DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.Internal.ReadOnlyDataSource.System.Web.UI.IDataSource.GetView(String viewName) +96
   DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.Internal.DataHelperCore.GetView() +321
   DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.Internal.DataHelper.PerformSelect() +133
   DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.Internal.DataContainer.PerformSelect() +187
   DevExpress.Web.ASPxScheduler.ASPxScheduler.DataBindCore() +90
   DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxDataWebControlBase.DataBindInternal() +290
   DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxWebControl.DataBind() +50
   DevExpress.Web.ASPxScheduler.ASPxScheduler.DataBind() +56
   DevExpress.Web.Mvc.SchedulerExtension.Bind(Object appointmentDataObject, Object resourceDataObject) +202
   System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute3(CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2) +1028
   ASP._Page_Views_Home_SchedulerPartial_cshtml.Execute() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\AstellasHDJ\Views\Home\SchedulerPartial.cshtml:1
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +280
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +128
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +199
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData) +150
   ASP._Page_Views_Home_Index_cshtml.Execute() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\AstellasHDJ\Views\Home\Index.cshtml:3
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +280
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +128
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +143
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +184
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +398
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__17() +33
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +649
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +287
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +240
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +37
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +53
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +51
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +606
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288
```

On the computer on which IIS is installed, there is no SQL Server (Express or anything) installed. Could it be linked?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the DEV Express scheduler that is highlighted as the source of the error is trying to retrieve data from some data source and that data source is specified as an instance of MS SQL Server. Try to identify the method in your code that provides that datasource, swap it with a mock source (a list of dummy objects of the relevant type, for example) and see what happens then. This may be of interest to you: [Scheduler Data Binding](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument11554/Binding)

Answer (score 0):

0x80131904 means you have no access to the db object you have no access to or the object does not excits. Check if the IIS user has access to your db, and if you connect to the right db. Then check if he has the right roles on your database.

For changing ownership of a table you can use:

```
EXEC sp_changeobjectowner @tablename, @username
```